# Error accessing an object property in an array

Tags: php

I am trying to access value of 'user' in the array below. I can't seem to get anything to show. This is my code:

```
$data = json_encode($values);
```

When I var_dump the above code, I get the below:

```
[
  {
    "user": "xxxx",
    "category": "xxxx",
    "email": "joe@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

Now I want to get value of 'user' and I did this:

```
echo $data[0]->user;
```

But this does not show anything.
Please what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As your using `json_encode($values)` to give you `$data`, `$data` is just a string - the JSON you show in the question, and `$data[0]->user` doesn't work on a string.

If you want the value of `user`, you should use your original data, I'm assuming `$values`...

```
echo $values[0]->user;
```